# Computing a line integral where the curve is in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute $\int \limits_{C} F.dr$ for $F(x,y)=(y,x)$ and $C$ is the curve given by $r=1+\theta$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$

**My Attempt**

Am I correct in saying that $F$ is a conservative vector field therefore path independent. Using this property I can calculate the integral by parameterising the line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(1+2\pi,0)$ and "ignoring" the curve the question gives me, as these are the start and end points of the curve.

$x = r\cos(\theta), y = r\sin(\theta)$.
Then, $\theta = 0 \Rightarrow r = 1,$ and $\theta = 2\pi \Rightarrow r= 1 +2\pi$.

Then, the integral is $f(2\pi,1+2\pi) - f(0,1)$, where $f = r^2sin\theta cos\theta$ (which is the potential function)

Therefore the answer is 0. Is this correct?

Comment: why did you delete your question related with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that $F$ is conservative with potential $f(x,y) = xy$, which in polar coordinates can also be written as $\tilde{f}(\theta,r)=r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta$. So, then $\int_C F\cdot dr$ does only depend on the start and end points. I suppose if you wanted to be very clear, you could show that the function you give is the potential of $F$, which is easier to do in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm slightly confused, why is it a problem that my second end point is in polar coordinates if I have converted the vector field into polar coordinates?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have re-written your potential function, I missed that the first time. You are fine then! Then the only issue I see is close to typographical, you should write $f(\theta,r) = r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ so we know what to plug in where in $f(2\pi,1+2\pi)-f(0,1)$.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much! I'm still slightly confused haha! I'm getting an answer of 0, however my curve is not closed, what does this represent?

Comment: So, interpreting this in terms of work, means that you think of $F$ as a force, and the line integral gives the total (signed) work done by $F$ as you move around $C$. So, with a conservative vector field you always get $0$ for a closed loop, but, that doesn't mean you *only* get $0$ for closed loops. Imagine the vector field $F(x,y) = (0,-y)$, which you can think of gravity pulling you straight down. If you walk from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ (think of the $x$-axis as the ground) then you have always moved perpendicular to the direction of the force, so it does no work on you, giving you $0$.